# AudioStreamer slider restarting music

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel, uislider, audiostreamer

I'm using the AudioStreamer class from mattgallagher for quite a few time but only now I am implementing the progress slider with the seconds info.

The label with timePlayed/totalDuration is working like a glove, and the seeker progress is being updated correctly.

The thing is when I move the slider to a new position is starts the streaming from the beginning with the slider on the new position.

I tried to track the AudioStreamer.m to see what I was missing but couldn't find. Is it a problem with the stream missing some info?

Comment: If you know answer please let me know as well

Comment: Can you please let me know how did you implement slider functionality.

Comment: I tried several branches but none worked. So I just gave up =/

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that in the `updateProgress` method, you are setting the sliders value so it keeps getting updated within the timer;

```
double progress = self.audio.progress;
double duration = self.audio.duration;
[progressSlider setValue:100 * progress / duration];
```

The what I did was create a method that gets called on the `Touch Up Inside` and `Touch Up Outside` event of the slider;

```
- (IBAction)endSeeking:(UISlider *)sender {
    double duration = self.audio.duration;
    double newtime = (duration / 100) * sender.value;
    [self.audio seekToTime:newtime];
}
```

Hope that helps.